# Display the number of votes a user has left for the day

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, voting

**([Migrated from UserVoice](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/219901-display-the-number-of-votes-a-user-has-left-for-the-day))**

So, after being on SO for a few weeks, it's obvious that there is a per-person limit of 30 votes per day.

I try to wisely use my daily SO votes to help build up the community and reward good questions and answers, as well as downvote answers that are unhelpful or incorrect. It's mildly annoying that I can't tell how many votes I have remaining until I get within the last 10, and then it only appears in a fleeting warning box.

It would be great to have the number of votes remaining appear in the header, next to envelope, reputation, badge count, etc. (Having it there instead of buried in some profile page/tab would be most useful to me.) Not only would it become easier to gauge how many I've used so far, but could also pique the curiosity of users who perhaps don't vote much or at all, such that they would click on it to see what the deal is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We had this originally (actual count) and it caused no end of friction. You have "enough" votes until you get close to running out, at which point we tell you how many are left.

Here's how it is now

- once you get below (n) votes the count is displayed
- above (n) votes the count is not displayed

This solution works and will not be changed.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed it would cause problems, but it's great to know and I can certainly accept that. Thanks, Jeff!

Answer (score 4):

I actually find the current way pretty good. I don't want to be overly conscious with the votes I have, if I feel I should vote, I should, and not take too much thought calculating if I've got enough votes preparing for the rest of the day.

The warning gives enough time to go undo a vote or be more cautious if you want to store some votes for the answers in a specific question or whatever.

Comment: That's very true, but I don't like to have to track down a specific vote I want to retract — it's much easier to plan ahead than to backtrack, at least for me. As far as "overly conscious", that's why it should be inconspicuous, like the envelope that highlights orange. It's almost unnoticeable, and certainly doesn't detract from the SO experience.

Comment: My point is that planning _that far_ ahead probably would detract value from the votes. 10 votes out of 30 is plenty of time to do whatever you've got planned. 30 votes out of 30 is way too much time.

Comment: I certainly allow for subjectivity. Realize that while 10 votes out of 30 is plenty for you, I would prefer to know from the get-go. Also, I don't see how knowing how many votes you have detracts from the value of the votes. Users can currently fling their votes willy-nilly just to use them up — all you have to do is vote until they're gone. I'm advocating careful premeditation and spending votes well. In the end, take this as my opinion, not gospel truth. :-)

Comment: Sure, and I disagree so I presented a different opinion :)

Answer (score 3):

This would be nice to find out. Until then, if you find yourself running out of votes, you can always go back and take away up or down votes on things you have already voted (typically within a 24 hour period I believe. After a certain time they just get locked).

Answer (score 0):

I had asked this same question on SO Meta. Things have changed since this was asked (~5yrs ago).

One can actually see the number of votes cast for the day on his profile page. A person has 40 daily votes (max.) so can subtract that from 40 to get his remaining votes.

I have experimented on this as well and it worked for me.

See the accepted answer on my question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297115/how-to-check-the-remaining-number-of-votes).