# Any easy way to see how many of my 30 votes I have remaining for today?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is there any easy way to see how many of my 30 votes I have remaining for today? I can't find any way to do this, easily.

Comment: It starts letting you know at 10 votes remaining, so...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no complete report of your voting.  Starting with 10 remaining for the day, this site will let you know when you cast a vote how many you have remaining.

Related, possibly dupe question:  [Display the number of votes a user has left for the day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/display-the-number-of-votes-a-user-has-left-for-the-day)

Comment: Seems to be 5 by now