# Can we get a vote-indicator at the top of the screen?

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display the number of votes a user has left for the day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/display-the-number-of-votes-a-user-has-left-for-the-day)

We have very nifty indicators of messages & current rep, how about a little indicator of how many votes have been used (or remain) on a daily basis?

Ever since [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80312/why-are-votes-per-post-on-the-decrease-what-can-we-do-to-improve-this) I've been trying to be conscious about voting but I never max-out the daily limit.  I'm often left wondering how much I actually contributed.  I'm sure there are ways to find out, but maybe a visual indicator in the core UI would also encourage people to use their votes.

Comment: FYI: When you have less then 10 (or was it 5?) votes left, the system will tell you every time you vote that "You have X votes left today."

Comment: -1 because I can't imagine a situation in which I'd need to track my votes this carefully, especially from the top bar.

Comment: @Popular Demand - Rep and Badges seem as unimportant as, and intimately-related-to, votes.  Both are featured prominently in the top bar.  I'm not feeling a *need* to track my votes, but a good amount of the value on this site is derived from votes so I don't see the harm in "raising awareness".

Comment: I agree that rep and badges aren't too important, but I'd say you're taking your logic in the wrong direction. Instead of adding votes to the top bar, we should be removing badges and rep. But at the very least, badges and rep are things you can look at as a measure of your achievements on the site; they're your score in the "SO as a video game" analogy. Votes, not so much.

Comment: @Popular Fair enough.  Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

There is an indication when you have last 5 votes to reach the daily limit voting.

Moreover, voting should be done for the question and answers based on how good it is rather than checking on how many votes you are left with.

Just continue to vote good questions and answers, dont worry about how many votes are left for the day.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wasn't aware of the "5 vote warning".